# Can't run HF model on GPU

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm trying to run wav2vec2 model on GPU and getting error.

```
DEVICE             = 'cuda'
wav2vec2_processor = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-base-960h")
wav2vec2_model     = Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-base-960h")    
wav2vec2_model.to(DEVICE)

file_name        = "myFile.wav"
speech, sr       = librosa.load(file_name, sr=16000)
input_values     = wav2vec2_processor(speech, sampling_rate=16000, return_tensors="pt").input_values
input_values.to(DEVICE)

logits           = wav2vec2_model(input_values).logits

predicted_ids    = torch.argmax(logits, dim=-1)
transcription    = wav2vec2_processor.decode(predicted_ids[0])
```

And getting error:

```
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same or input should be a MKLDNN tensor and weight is a dense tensor
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2):

You should move your data to GPU too

```
speech = torch.from_numpy(speech).cuda()
```